# Alternative to building query with messy scopes?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating a query through Ruby to generate a report.

```
query = Account.includes(:assets, :location, :category)
```

the report request has multiple optional parameters (e.g. category could be sent in, or it could not be initialized at all).

Currently, I consider these after establishing and assigning the query by applying scopes

```
if category.present?
  cat = Category.find_by_name(category)
  query = query.in_category(cat) if cat.present?
end
```

the scope being

```
scope :in_category, lambda { |category|
    where("#{table_name}.category_id = :category_id", :category_id => category.id)
  }
```

I do this multiple times and it is functional.  I would prefer a single Where condition being built for readability (as opposed to having to read 10 scopes to understand the actual query).

Is there a clean way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
 Account.includes(:assets, :location, :category).joins(:category).where(Category.arel_table[:name].eq(category))
```